# Split two digit int

Tags: c#, math, int

I would like to split a two digit int into 2 one digit ints! For example:

```
20 = 2 and 0

15 = 1 and 5

8  = 0 and 8
```

Comment: An `int` never has 2 digits. It always has 32 bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's easy: use `%` to get the mod of the number, and `/` for the integer division (i.e. division where the fractional part is discarded).

Your numbers are in the decimal system (i.e. the base is `10`) so you divide and mod by 10, like this:

```
int a = 20 / 10; // 2
int b = 20 % 10; // 0
```

To print a number digit-by-digit, least significant digit first, you can use this loop:

```
int a = 12345;
while (a != 0) {
    lastDigit = a % 10;
    Console.WriteLine(lastDigit);
    a /= 10;
}
```

Comment: and whats if I have 8? (and want to get 0 and 8)

Comment: @Michael The same thing will work, too: `8/10` gives you zero, `8%10` remains `8`.

Comment: @Michael Did you try it? This code obviously works for `8`. It does not work for values outsize `0`...`99`, but those aren't two digit ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 45; // or anything you want

int firstDigit = i / 10;
int secondDigit = i % 10;
```

It's quite simple really.
You can do this for 3-digit numbers using a Modulos and Division operations as well, but I'll let you figure that out by yourself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , easy.

```
int m =2123;
int n=m;
while (n != 0) { 
    y=n%10; //variable holds each digit out of the number m.
    Console.WriteLine(y);
    n /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a array of integers then you can very well use LINQ, else just use any of the below answers.

```
int num = 86;
int digit1 = num / 10;
int digit2 = num % 10;
```

Do your numbers have only two digits?

Answer (score 0):

```
        int input = 15;
        int first = 0;
        int second = Math.DivRem(input, 10, out first);
```